# ¿Por qué me da el error Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php, mysql

Éste es el código de receptor.php:

```
<?php
$user_name = "***";
$password = "***";
$host = "***";
$db_name = "***";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user_name,$password,$db_name);

$sql = "select * from ***;";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    array_push($response,array("Fecha"=>$row["fecha"],"Hora"=>$row["hora"],"Supermercado"=>$row["supermercado"],"Compra"=>$row["compra"],"Calle"=>$row["calle"],"Numero"=>$row["numero"],"Piso"=>$row["piso"]));

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Al probar el código anterior en `XAMPP` no me da ningún tipo de problema y obtengo el resultado esperado. El problema viene que cuando el mismo código lo subo a un servidor en Internet me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: fecha in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: hora in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: supermercado in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: compra in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: calle in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: numero in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: piso in /xyz/public_html/receptor.php on line 14 on line 14

Esto es lo que obtengo:

```
[{"Fecha":null,"Hora":null,"Supermercado":null,"Compra":null,"Calle":null,"Numero":null,"Piso":null}]<br>
```

Y ésta es la estructura de la base de datos:

```
fecha          varchar(100)     utf8_unicode_ci
hora           varchar(100)     utf8_unicode_ci 
supermercado   varchar(16)      utf8_unicode_ci
compra         varchar(100000)  utf8_unicode_ci
numero         varchar(4)       utf8_unicode_ci
piso           varchar(4)       utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Podrias añadir el codigo de `receptor.php`

Comment: El código de receptor.php es el que está arriba de todo.

Comment: Prueba este código, para que te muestre el nombre de las columnas que hay en tu tabla. Te ayudará a depurar: `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $val)
        {
            echo "<td>" .$key. ': ' . $val . "</td>";
        }
            echo '</tr>';
}`

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que el servicio de free hosting que ofrece 000webhost tiene desactivadas las funciones de Remote MySQL, por eso me retorna null en todos los valores, ya que es el propio servidor que no deja acceder a ellos. La solución sería comprar un host.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es porque en el `php.ini` de `XAMPP` debes tener configurado el [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) para que no muestre los `Notices`.

Soluciones:

- Editar `php.ini` del servidor online y configurar el `error_reporting` para que no notifique los `NOTICE`:

  ```
  error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
  ; Notificar todos los errores excepto los NOTICE
  ```
- Utilizar la función [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php) y desactivar solo los `NOTICE` al principio de tu `receptor.php`.

  ```
  <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  $user_name = "***";

  $password = "***";
  ....
  ```

Comment: Perfecto, los Notice los sacó. El problema es que aún teniendo los campos rellenados en la tabla (es decir, el campo fecha tiene un valor en la base de datos, al igual que supermercado, etc... Ninguno está vacío) Me retorna null para cada una de las variables Fecha, Hora, etc.

Comment: @Joshua, ¿podrías agregar en tu pregunta la estructura de la tabla consultada y/o el resultado de hacer `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: El resultado de var_dump($row); es un NULL y ya edité mi pregunta poniendo la estructura de la base de datos, espero que sea eso ya que mis conocimientos aún están muy verdes. Destaco también que uso un plan tipo free hosting (000webhost), desconozco si hay algún tipo de restricción en ese aspecto.

Comment: @Joshua, la función `mysqli_fetch_array` (con `i`), no existe. En cambio `mysql_fetch_array` (sin `i`) si. ¿Estas seguro de que ese es el código y funciona?

Comment: Si funciona, en mi servidor local con XAMPP obtengo el contenido de todos los campos de la tabla. Probé a sacárselo y me da este error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Estuve investigando acerca de este free hosting que ofrece 000webhost y tiene desactivadas las funciones de Remote MySQL, por eso me retorna null en todos los valores, ya que es el propio host que no deja acceder a ellos. Gracias Marcos.

Comment: @Joshua, agrega una respuesta donde expliques que el problema y la solución. Dentro de 3 días podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es que el `php.ini` de ambos servidores están configurados de forma diferente, el local tiene desactivados esos `warnings`, eso quiere decir que también suceden en local pero no se marcan en el `log` por configuración.

Pasando al tema de la programación, el problema es la linea:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

Si lo declaras de esa forma, el resultado no es un array asociativo, es uno numerico. Por lo tanto para accesar debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$row[0], $row[1], $row[3]...
```

para recibir un array asociativo debes agregar un parámetro extra:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```